# Add reference from Visual Basic project to C# DLL

Tags: .net, vb.net

I've a Visual Studio solution that built some .Net DLLs written in C#. The DLLs are then copied to another path defined in environment system variable.

Now I want to add this DLL as reference to another Visual Basic project without specifying the full path but just... `%LIB_PATH%\csharpdll.dll`

Is it possible?

**Edit** 
I'll write better my question: I'm using Visual C# and VB 2010 express. I've a C# project that I'll call CShartProject as shared library. Now I want integrate this project into an exiting VB project. Unfortunatly I cannot have mixed language solution with express edition...

Now the solution must be shared from 2 remote pc... so I want avoid relative paths. What can I do?

Comment: Why don't you try by yourself? You may have taken more time to write the question than trying in Visual Studio, don't you?

Comment: I'm a C++ software developer and I've no expirence with VB... When I push add reference... I have only to choose a file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Project Properties -> References -> Add... Reference -> Browse tab, then browse to your C# DLL.

Regarding relative paths, your best bet would probably be to leave absolute paths on development machine and then set up PATH to point to your %LIB_PATH%. This way you have it working on a remote machine as well.

It is always best to make *project* references. This makes it more developer friendly. For example, another developer can checkout your branch, open solution and have it working without modifying environment variables. Also, you can debug your C# code and commit those changes, if needed.